# How to use Oracle "partitioning by reference" in tables with 2 foreign keys?

Tags: oracle, partitioning

A little bit late in the project we have realized that we need to use Oracle (11G) partitioning both for performance and admin of the data.
We have an hierarchical entity model with lots of @OneToMany and @OneToOne relationships, and some entities are referenced from 2 or more other entities.
We want to use "partitioning by range" (month) on the "parent/root" entity and "partition by reference" on all child entities. After a year we will move the oldest month partition to an archive db. It's a 24-7 system so the data continuously grows.

From the Oracle documentation: "Reference partitioning allows the partitioning of two tables related to one another by referential constraints. The partitioning key is resolved through an existing parent-child relationship, enforced by enabled and active primary key and foreign key constraints."

Is it possible to use "partition by reference" on a table when there are 2 foreign keys and one of them can be null?
(From what I read you have to use "not null" on the foreign key for "partition by reference")

A small example to illustrate the problem:

```
A - parent entity
B - child entity to A
C - child entity to A or B

create table 
A (
   id number primary key,
   adate date
)
partition by range (adate) (
   partition p1 values less than (to_date('20130501','yyyymmdd')),
   partition p2 values less than (to_date('20130601','yyyymmdd')),
   partition pm values less than (maxvalue)
);

create table 
B (
   id number primary key,
   text varchar2(5),
   a_id number not null,
   constraint fk_ba foreign key (a_id) references A
)
partition by reference(fk_ba);

create table 
C (
   id number primary key,
   text varchar2(5),
   a_id number not null, -- NOT POSSIBLE as a_id or b_id will be null..
   b_id number not null, -- NOT POSSIBLE as a_id or b_id will be null..
   constraint fk_ca foreign key (a_id) references A,
   constraint fk_cb foreign key (b_id) references B
)
partition by reference(fk_ca)
partition by reference(fk_cb);
```

Thanks for any advice.
/Mats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot partition by two foreign keys.

If A is parent of B and B is parent of C i would suggest partitioning C by fk_cb. weather you'l gain max pruning when joining A and C - thats an interesting question, why wont you run a test for us ?

question - why you have FK of A in table C. isn't A implied by the fk to B ?

(my guess, technically it's possible but oracle would have to access table B. i dont think he will do that so i think you wont get prunning).

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  In our object model (projected on this example) there can exist: A->B->C or A->C (e.g. an error on parent object or on the child object). Maybe we have to redesign so it looks like this: A->B->C1 or A->C2, but it feels wrong to do that as the entity/table C1 and C2 will have the same attributes.. (We would have to duplicate about 10 tables and just give them different names)

Comment: We will redesign so that all child tables only have one parent as described in my comment above.